# ¿Cómo puedo llamar a un campo mediante la selección de un ID?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, id

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al momento de autocompletar el primer campo llene el segundo con lo que se haya rellenado este primero?:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input id="nombre1" name="razonsocial" type="text" autocomplete="off" required title="Completar campo" class="typeahead_2 form-control" onkeyup="PasarValor();" <?php
if($_COOKIE["lvl"]==2){
    echo 'value="'. $_COOKIE["usuario"] . '" disabled';
}
?> />
                                    <input id="idCliente" name="idCliente" type="hidden" value="<?php
if($_COOKIE["lvl"]==2){
    echo $_COOKIE["idUsuario"];
}
?>" />
                                </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cuota Base (%)</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                    <input id="valor2" type="text" onkeyUp="calcular()" name="cuota" required title="Completar campo" class="form-control m-b">
                                </div>
```

Necesito que la información que contiene ese registro la inserte al seleccionarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el php donde hago el insert:

```html
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $razonSocial = $_POST["razonsocial"];
    $idCliente = $_POST["idCliente"];
    $cliente = $_POST["Cliente"];
    $rfc = $_POST["rfc"];
    $moneda = $_POST["moneda"];
    $mercancia = $_POST["mercancia"];
    $importe = $_POST["importe"];
    $tipoOperacion = $_POST["TipoOperacion"];
    $fechaAlta = $_POST["FechaAlta"];
    $detalles = $_POST["detalles"];
    $tipoTransporte = $_POST["TipoTransporte"];
    $fechaSalida = $_POST["FechaSalida"];
    $fechaLlegada = $_POST["FechaLlegada"];
    $folio = $_POST["folio"];
    $porigen = $_POST["porigen"];
    $eorigen = $_POST["eorigen"];
    $corigen = $_POST["corigen"];
    $pdestino = $_POST["pdestino"];
    $edestino = $_POST["edestino"];
    $cdestino = $_POST["cdestino"];
    $coberturas1 = $_POST["Coberturas1"];
    $coberturas2 = $_POST["Coberturas2"];
    $coberturas3 = $_POST["Coberturas3"];
    $coberturas4 = $_POST["Coberturas4"];
    $cuota = $_POST["cuota"];
    $prima = $_POST["prima"];
    $gastosexp = $_POST["gastosexp"];
    $iva = $_POST["iva"];
    $total = $_POST["total"];
    
        
    if($cliente == 'X'){
        $cliente ='';
  
    }else{
       query("INSERT INTO merca (idViaje, idCliente, Cliente, rfc, moneda, mercancia, 
importe, TipoOperacion, FechaAlta, detalles, TipoTransporte, FechaSalida, 
FechaLlegada, folio, porigen, eorigen, corigen, pdestino, edestino, cdestino, 
Coberturas1, Coberturas2, Coberturas3, Coberturas4, cuota, prima, gastosexp, iva, total) VALUES 
(DEFAULT,'".$idCliente."', '".$cliente."', '".$rfc."', '".$moneda."', 
'".$mercancia."', '".$importe."', '".$tipoOperacion."', '".$fechaAlta."', 
'".$detalles."', '".$tipoTransporte."', '".$fechaSalida."', '".$fechaLlegada."', 
'".$folio."','".$porigen."','".$eorigen."', '".$corigen."', '".$pdestino."', 
'".$edestino."', '".$cdestino."', '".$coberturas1."', '".$coberturas2."', '".$coberturas3."', '".$coberturas4."', '".$cuota."', 
'".$prima."', '".$gastosexp."', '".$iva."', '".$total."')");
       
}
}
?>
```

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.get('inc/json-clientes.php', function(data) {
                $(".typeahead_2").typeahead({
                    source: data,
                    afterSelect: function(data) {
                        $('#idCliente').val(data.code);
                    }
                });
            }, 'json');

            $("#ncliente").validate({
                rules: {
                    razonsocial: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    },
                    cliente: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    },
                    rfc: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 12
                    },
                    Cliente: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    }

                }
            });
        });

    </script>

    <script>
        function PasarValor() {
            document.getElementById("nombre2").value = document.getElementById("nombre1").value;
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Muestra el código relevante del autocompletado (Javascript + PHP)

Comment: Ya lo agregue a la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

He visto eso que pides, pero no recuerdo donde lo encontré, te dejo este código que yo utilizo para enviar valores desde la selección en un combobox (select), es solo una idea que quizás te pueda ayudar

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Personal").on('change', function () {
        $("#Personal  option:selected").each(function () {
            var Numero_Empleado = $(this).val();
            alert (Numero_Empleado);
            $('input[name=Numero_Empleado]').val($(this).val());
        });
   });
});
```